# Trigger alert when there is a change to ember data / model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have the following route that will poll a model and refresh the data at a given interval. What I'm trying to do is trigger an alert when a new record is available in the model. I'm new to this, so I'm having some trouble figuring out how to trigger an alert site-wide without simply triggering it each time the model refreshes. I tried using 'didCreate' in the model, but it doesn't seem to recognize new records.

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import Ember from 'ember'

export const pollInterval = 8000 // time in milliseconds
export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    pat: this.store.findAll('pat'),
    appt: this.store.findAll('appt')
    })
   },

  getSMS () {
    return this.get('store').findAll('smstext')
   },

  onPoll ()  {
     return this.getSMS()
    .then((users) => {
       this.set('currentModel', users)
        })
   },

  afterModel () {
     let smsPoller = this.get('smsPoller')
     if (!smsPoller) {
        smsPoller = this.get('pollboy').add(this, this.onPoll, pollInterval)
        this.set('smsPoller', smsPoller)
      }
   },

 setupController(controller, models) {
     controller.set('huddle', models.huddleappt);
     controller.set('pat', models.pat);
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use a service for this use case. You can inject your service wherever you need the data, and in the service you can handle the polling.

You can then display your data like this.

In your component file:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend({
  smsService: service(),
  smsData: computed('smsService.data')

  // ...
```

And in your template you can access your data with the computed property from your components js file